# Menu Listener Action Performed

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem, jmenubar

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.MenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.MenuListener;
import java.awt.*;

class displaymsg extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String args []){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu supply = new JMenu("supply");
        JMenuItem addnew = new JMenuItem("add");

        addnew.addMenuListener(new MenuListener(){
            @Override
            public void menuSelected(MenuEvent me){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"under construction");
            }
        });
        f.add(mb); mb.add(supply);
        supply.add("New Product");
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setJMenuBar(mb);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

this is my code for menuListener but I didn't get how to do this
If anyone has any ideas on what I may be doing wrong, please point it out

Comment: `but I didn't get how to do this` - Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for working examples. Keep a link to the tutorial handy as it contains examples for all Swing basics.

Answer (score 1):

See comments in the following [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

//see https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions
//the class does not need to extend JFrame if not used as JFrame
public class DisplayMsg{

    public static void main(String args []){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        JMenu supply = new JMenu("Supply");
        supply.add("New Product");
        JMenuItem addNew = new JMenuItem("Add"); //naming conventions

        addNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"under construction");
            }
        });

        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        mb.add(supply);
        mb.add(addNew); //missing in your code
        //f.add(mb); this would add the menu to the content pane 
        f.setJMenuBar(mb); 

        f.setSize(400, 400);
        //f.setLayout(null);  // do not use null layout
                              //see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

MenuListener can be added toJMenu, not to  JMenuItem. If you want to use it 
change `addNew` to `JMenu` :

```
    JMenu addNew = new JMenu("Add"); 
    addNew.addMenuListener(new MenuListener(){
        @Override
        public void menuSelected(MenuEvent me){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"under construction");
        }

        @Override
        public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {}
    });
```

Comment: @esQmo_  thanks, but I have already too many open channels (0:

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. Here's the point. Menu is a way of organizing things. You have a `JMenuBar`, which consists of set of `Menu`s. Each Menu has set of `MenuItems`. You just add an `ActionListener` to the `MenuItem` to handle events.

```
public class DisplayMsg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu supply;
        JMenuItem addnew;
        supply = new JMenu("supply");
        addnew = new JMenuItem("add");
        // JButton b = new JButton("click me");
        // b.setBounds(100,120,100,40);
        addnew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "under construction");

            }
        });
        // f.add(b);
        f.add(mb);
        mb.add(supply);
        supply.add(addnew);
        supply.add("New Product");
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setJMenuBar(mb);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: @sanjaYbhandari The protocol here is either to up vote, down vote or mark it as the answer. Just FYI since you are a novice person here.

Comment: What does it add to the previously posted answer ?

Comment: It is slightly different. In previous answer `mb.add(addNew);` but in mine it is `supply.add(addnew);`

Comment: @c0der Previous answer adds menuitem to the menubar, but mine adds menuitem to the menu. That's the major difference between the two to me.